# How to find out who's causing an access violation error?

Tags: delphi, vb6, windows-vista, crash, access-violation

I'm getting reports that my app is causing a GPF on some Vista machines. The error message is something like this:

access violation at 0x75784062 ( tried to write to 0x00000006)

In order to fix this, I first need to know exactly who is causing this GPF: my main exe, some third party component, one of my own activex components, a dll, etc...

How can I find this out? What tools can pinpoint the exact module that caused this mess?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS My app is coded in VB6 and my activex controls are written in Delphi 2007.

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/tracking-access-violation-483209.html), there should be a "Find Error" function which will help you locate the problem

Answer (score 10):

My suggestion would be to try either MadExcept [link text](http://www.madshi.net/) or Eurekalog [link text](http://www.eurekalog.com/) . These capture the unhandled exception and produce a stack dump at the point where the problem occurs.

No link to these other than as a satisfied customer. MadExcept has enabled me to track down and eliminate some very rare problems in my programs.

Comment: Bah! Beaten at the goal line ;-)

Comment: Great suggestion, although I wonder if it works in this case. The application is VB6 and only the ActiveX control used in the application is written in Delphi.

Comment: From the rough outline of the error message, it does not sound like the VB6 part that is causing the error. The guy in my office who does the VB6 work says it's quite tricky (but not impossible) to create this error.

Anyway, I think it's always better to try to trap/handle as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommand some kind of Exception-hook, like [Eurekalog](http://www.eurekalog.com/) or [madExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) that gives you a nice callstack when exceptions occurs.

Now this want help you much now, of cource...

I have not had any luck with the 'Find error' dialog. Generaly, a consistent failing case and a lot of stepping is the only/fastest/easiest solution. If it is a case of uninitialized pointer or freed object, FastMM4 may help you with the right settings.

Comment: eurekalog is buggy itself :) go for madshi

Answer (score 1):

When the program crashes Windows should save a [crash dump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263). You can then load this in WinDbg or, at a pinch, Visual Studio. There are various ways to analyze the dump to find out what went wrong. To get you started:

- Get [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)
- [Configure the MS symbol server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)
- Load the crash dump
- Run command "analyze -v"

Comment: what if I get an AV but the program does not crash (so no dmp file)?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) and monitor your app, he generate DUMP file for you and have analyze to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Process Monitor or Process Explorer, both from the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) site.

Comment: and use them how?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking down AVs may be difficult because the real reason may not be in the same point where the exception actually occurs. Some general tips:

1. Look at the address. DLLs (including
   ActiveX/OCX), are loaded at higher
   address, usually beyond 0x50000000
   (systemm DLLs are usually in
   0x70000000 to 0x78000000). It looks your AV happens in a DLL. Remember in latest version of Windows address space load randomization can change addresses for each run
2. A call stack is very valuable to understand how the code got to the AV. Besides EurekaLog and MadExcept, the JCL/JVCL libraries have usueful to obtain those informations. You may need to compile with more debugging informations (and map files) to obtain a useful call stack.
3. Delphi has a Goto address debugging feature that allows to load an application, pause it in the debugger and then jump to an address. But it requires the address didn't change meanwhile (recompiling with modification will probably change the address, and randomization will do as well).
4. If the error is not replicable on your development machine, you can try the remote debugger to debug an application running on another machine.

Comment: Is ASLR (address space load randomisation) applicable? From what I've read it needs to be explicitly enabled for your application.